# Expokit realization on Python

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I am looking for a Pythonic realization of **Expokit**, which is a software package that provides matrix exponential routines for small dense or very large sparse matrices, real or complex, i.e. it finds

```
w(t) = exp(t*A)*v
```

This package had been realized in Fortran and Matlab and can be found here https://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/

I have found a python wrapper **expokitpy**
 https://github.com/weinbe58/expokitpy and a Krylov subspace methods package **KryPy** [https://github.com/andrenarchy/krypy](https://krypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Both seem to be relevant, however neither of them goes with good enough documentation (for me) to do time-evolution.

Does somebody have a working solution with the packages mentioned above or similar?

Answer (score 2):

In case this is still useful to someone, it looks like there was an effort to [incorporate expokit within scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/354) which has now stalled and is looking for somebody to finish. Though [here are some instructions](http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/faster-expm-td10629.html) to compile with Fortran and then run via Python, with good results.

It seems also to have been adopted by [slepc4py](https://slepc.upv.es/documentation/slepc.pdf), which is then used by [quimb](https://quimb.readthedocs.io/en/0.4.0/index.html), which seems useful if you need it for quantum information (or just use its expm and expm_multiply methods).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to quimb and it does sound as a relevant incorporation to scipy! I hope to take a look at both things eventually.